Papers showing two open problems are connected
I'm currently writing an article in which I connect two open problems from different fields of mathematics (group theory and combinatorics). While writing the introduction, I was trying to think of other examples of two problems from different fields of mathematics that are connected.
I could only think of the modularity theorem (formerly known as the Taniyama–Shimura–Weil conjecture) and Fermat's Last Theorem. Both are now solved, but historically, it was first shown that they are related; more specifically, that a negative answer to Fermat's Last Theorem would yield a negative answer to the Taniyama-Shimura-Weil conjecture.
My question is: What are other examples of such connections?
Edit: based on coLaidernotte's suggestion, the type of connections I'm looking for can better be described as follows: examples of two (or more) open problems that are not considered related at first, but which are eventually proved in a uniform way or proved to be closely related.

Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to like 30 things at least.

In what sense do you think the TSW conjecture and Fermat’s Last Theorem are from different fields of mathematics? For me they are both from the algebraic number theory.

@coLaideronnette They are indeed both from algebraic number theory, but the TSW-conjecture also deals with modular forms, which is related to algebraic geometry, IIRC.

The application of modern algebro-geometric tools to problems in number theory goes back to 1950s, there is no reason to isolate them from the general problems. Also, the study of modular forms and the rational points of algebraic varieties in number theory began long before the TSW conjecture was proposed.

Thank you for the elaboration, I did not know that.

Great, now back to your question. I think “open problems that are not considered relevant at first but eventually proved in a uniform way(or proved to be closely related)“ is a reasonable modification of your statement. Then Deligne’s proof of the Weil conjecture and the Ramanujan–Petersson conjecture is immediately a good example.

Often people do interesting work translating a famous open problem to very different language from a different field (see e.g. the discrepancy theory reinterpretation of Kadison-Singer, the quantum games interpretation of Connes’ embedding problem, or work of Kronheimer-Mrowka on the four color theorem). But it would be really amazing if two famous open problems from different fields were “secretly the same” (although I guess coLaideronnette provided an example!)

This is way too broad.

At the risk of shameless self-promotion (oh well, here goes...) I recently published a paper with John Greenlees, "Modules with finitely generated cohomology, and singularities of C*BG" showing that a conjecture in algebraic topology is equivalent to a conjecture in modular representation theory, in quite a non-trivial way. But I agree with Andy, the question is way too broad.

NP complete problems might be an example.

Related: Your favorite surprising connections in mathematics.
